# Matrix multiplication in R, strange results

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

While checking some matrix multiplication operations, I came across a strange behavior. I get different results when I perform the multiplication "by hand" (using the product and the sum) and when using the matrix multiplication operator %*%.

```
c <- 1:10
a <- 100^(0:9)
p1 <- sum(a*c)
p2 <- a%*%c
p1==p2
      [,1]
[1,] FALSE
p1-p2
      [,1]
[1,] -2048
```

However, when I use any other value for a (e.g., a <- 101^0:9) , I do get the same results:

```
c <- 1:10
a <- 101^(0:9)
p1 <- sum(a*c)
p2 <- a%*%c
p1==p2
      [,1]
[1,] TRUE
p1-p2
      [,1]
[1,] 0
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you,
Pedro

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal). Use `all.equal` to test for equality.

Comment: While this is in the R-FAQ,  seeing as it's really a "computer math for newbies" FAQ, is there somewhere in SO we could place the answer?

Comment: "Any other value" is not necessarily OK.  Try `f <- function(b) { a <- b^(0:9); c<- 1:10; sum(a*c) - a %*% c }; bvec <- 80:120; r <- sapply(bvec,f); plot(bvec,r,type="b")`

Answer (score 2):

`%*%` does compute its results in a slightly different way, which means that different rounding errors occur at different places, leading to a different overall result.

I'm just guessing, but I believe that this *might* be due to `sum` keeping its accumulator in a machine floating point register, which has [80 bit extended precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format) on Intel architectures. If you want to know for certain, you'd have to look at the assembly code of R.

Comment: If you're going to go that route, you could convert the data to `mpfr` class (see the `Rmpfr` package).